# What do these references mean in George RR Martin's "In the House of the Worm"?

Tags: history, the-thousand-worlds

In the short story "In the House of the Worm", the main character gets to see a panel (sort of mural) that depicts

> an intricate, labored depiction of sword-swinging *grouns* battling a giant whose eyes were **thetas** and whose fingers were worms. [The main character] had to look hard and long to make sense of the scene, however; as with the tapestries of the *yaga-la-hai*, here too the colors were dim and fading, and rust had eaten black, flaking holes in some of the panels.

As opposed to the main character, I couldn't make much sense of the scene. I recognized though, the constant references to

> the **theta** sign, the one employed by the *Federal Empire's Ecological Engineering Corps* in *Tuf Voyaging*, another of Martin's tales (or series of tales).

I know that George R.R. Martin creates highly detailed worlds which are consistent for many of his different stories. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to gather much about the relationship between the aforementioned sigil, the people who used it, and the different species living in *In the House of the Worm*.

I was hoping somebody could help me to put some of the pieces of that puzzle together. What is the background history for the events depicted in *In the House of the Worm*, in relation to the scene depicted in that panel and the

> Ecological Engineers?

Comment: Is it not just referring to the greek letter? The one on the left looks like an eye (somewhat reptilian). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta#mediaviewer/File:Theta_uc_lc.svg

Comment: No, that sign identifies the people I indicated in the _spoilers_. It is not _just a symbol_. It has a special meaning and properties, within the context of these stories. And the worms in this tory are worms, not _wyrms_ nor anything reptilian. I strongly believe they are related to the people who whore that sigil, but couldn't put all the pieces together.